# What is cascading in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

What is *cascading* in Hibernate ? There is a `cascade` attribute I have seen in the `map` tag. What is it meant for?

Like what does `cascade = all` mean? There are other attributes I read like
`cascade="none|save-update|delete|all-delete-orphan|delete-orphan"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cascading is about persistence actions involving one object propagating to other objects via an association.  Cascading can apply to a variety of Hibernate actions, and it is typically transitive.  The "cascade=..." attribute of the annotation that defines the association says what actions should cascade for that association.

Cascade = "all" means to apply all primary cascade types.  As of Hibernate 5.3, these types are:

- "delete" / "remove",
- "detach" / "evict",
- "merge",
- "lock",
- "persist",
- "refresh",
- "replicate",
- "save_update" / "update"

(Some of those cascade type names are old and/or deprecated.)

There are three more compound types:

- "all_delete_orphan" - means the same as "all" plus enabling the deletion of entities that are orphaned by the cascading.
- "delete_orphan" - means "delete" plus orphan deletion.
- "none" - means no cascading.

Answer (score 7):

Cascading is Hibernate's way of using transitive persistence model. Transitive persistence is a technique that allows you to propagate persistence to transient (object not yet saved in database) and detached sub-graphs (child objects) automatically. For example, a newly created child object of already persistent parent object should automatically become persistent without a call to save() or persist() methods.

Cascading in Hibernate has many options like save-update, persist, merge, delete etc. Cascade='all' is a way to apply all cascading options.